# Push to array safely, how to? Worry or not?

Tags: javascript

I think this may be a naive question.  I often find that I've got multiple xhr requests waiting on returns.  I keep track of the requests I've issued in a JavaScript array. that is, when a new request is made, I add it to the array, then when the thread completes I remove it from the array.

In a multi-threaded OS, I'd be worried about threads crossing but I know JavaScript is single threaded.  Should I worry about the array being consistent?

Sorry if this has been asked and and answered.  I looked and did not find a link around array safe push.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you should not worry about it. JavaScript is single-threaded, like you said.

Comment: Are there any special "locked" regions in JavaScript? That is, I think someone told me that xhr success events run completely before any other async event interrupts them.  That is, if two success completion events of xhr requests happen, are both event handlers guaranteed to run without being task switched out once they start?

Comment: @PeterKellner: Yes, they are. And no, there are no locked regions in JavaScript, because it's single-threaded and that would make no sense. For what it's worth, for other matters of (non-thread) synchronization, you would use callbacks.

Comment: sorry, still confused.  do call backs complete before they are task switched out?  that is when a callback starts, can another call back interrupt it?

Comment: @PeterKellner: No, and sorry if that confused you. There is no parallel task switching in JavaScript. When one task is done, another can begin. Otherwise, they wait.

Comment: when you say a task, does that mean a function call?  if I have a function that calls another function that calls another function, on any of the function calls themselves, is that a time at which a task switch to something like a xhr success function might be called?