# Synchronos file read in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, closures

I have the following file-selector dialog. I want to allow selection of multiple files. After the files are selected, I want to render a preview of the selected files. My code is:

```
<input
          type="file"
          multiple
          accept=".png, .jpeg"

          onChange={e => {
            this.setState({ previews: [] });

            if (!e.target.files) {
              return;
            }

            var previews = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
              var file = e.target.files[i];
              (function(file, previews) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                  // console.log(e.target.result);
                  console.log("Just pushed a new preview");
                  previews.push(e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
              })(file, previews);
            }

            console.log("All files read");
            // I want this to be called only after
            // all the file contents are read
            this.setState({ previews });
          }}
        />
```

However, with the above code, my `Just pushed a new preview` is printed after `All files read` is printed on the console.

Is there a way for me to make the FileReader loop (the closure) finish and then the `this.setState({previews})` get called ?

All this code is in a react file, if it matters.

Comment: It is async as to not block the main thread. That might lead to page not responding depending on the file size. So its not allowed in the page. However (FileReaderSync)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync] is present which is accessible in `workers`.

Comment: You can add a check in the `onLoad` callback and `set previews` if it all files have been read.

Comment: How will I get to know if all the files are read, in the `onLoad` callback. I have no way to pass either `i` or `e.target.files.length` to the `onLoad` callback. Even if I find a way to pass the index and total length, I cannot reliably know that all files are read. The 5th file read may finish ahead of the 3rd file read, etc. Or is there any other way ?

Comment: You dont have to pass it. You can just access `i` and `e.target` inside your `function` as they are inside the parent scope.

Comment: Yes, I do not have to pass them. I agree. But if the 5th file read gets completed before the 3rd file read, I will not have a way to know that all file reads are completed (unless I maintain some kind of totalFilesRead variable which could get overlapping writes).

Comment: -_- All you have to do is to keep  a count of how many files are read so far(inside your onLoad callback). Then in the `onLoad` (probably in the end) you have to check if the read count is same as the number of files selected. Done.

Comment: Wouldn't that be thread unsafe, unless I use a lock to protect the counter ? It definitely is a race condition in other languages.

Comment: Nop. As far as i know javascript is `async` but not multi-threaded. So no race condition issues. Multi-thread is supported via web-workers from HTML5. In your case you dont have to worry about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move setState inside onLoad event. Since file reader is async, so setting state outside onLoad will trigger it before the event completes and would result in an empty or incomplete `previews` array.

```
 var previews = [];
 var s = this;

 for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
   var file = e.target.files[i];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        previews.push(e.target.result);
        s.setState({ previews });
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be thread unsafe ? Two different threads can set previews to a bad value in parallel ?

Comment: @SankarP No it wouldn't be since a local previews array inside the method is being appended and its copy is being maintained in state. Moreover, thread handling is less of a concern when working with js.

Comment: @SankarP fyr : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163175/push-to-array-safely-how-to-worry-or-not

Comment: I have accepted the answer as it solves the problem. Thanks. However, I believe that the correct answer would be something that uses (something like promises) to ensure that all previews.push is completed and then setState is called only once to set the correct previews array in the state. We could use something like WaitGroups too. I'm not criticising your answer but just feel that there must be a purer solution.

Comment: Also, there is an edit needed to your code. `this.setState` did not work. So we needed to assign `var s = this` prior to entering the loop (after initializing `previews`) and then call `s.setState`. It will be good if you can edit the answer. Thanks a lot for your code :-)

Comment: @SankarP Glad it helped. Maybe you can update when you find a better solution. Also i've edited the answer as you've mentioned for `this` :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Promise.all to wait for all promises to be done to know that all files are processed or not.  And also, you need to update the state as soon as you are done reading the file. Better add a progress bar and setState for updating it.

```
var Sample = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () { return { previews: [], allfilesdone:false }; }, 
  render: function() {
    var p = this.state.previews.map((p) => <div>{p}</div>);
    return (
      <div style = {this.styler}>
        <input id="upload" multiple
          accept=".txt" type="file"
           onClick={(e) => this.setState({allfilesdone: false})}
           onChange={(event)=> { 
                var s = this;
                this.setState({previews:[], allfilesdone: false});
                var fs = event.target.files;
                Promise.all([...fs].map((file) => {
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                    reader.onload = (ev) => {
                        resolve(ev.target.result);
                        var pt = this.state.previews;
                        pt.push(ev.target.result);
                        s.setState({previews: pt});
                    }
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                  });
                }))
                  .then(ft => {
                        this.setState({allfilesdone: true});
                      });
            }}/>
        <div>all processed: {this.state.allfilesdone?"true":"false"}</div>
        <div>number of files: {this.state.previews.length}</div>
        <div>{p}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <Sample />, 
  document.getElementById('mount-point'));
```

Comment: I used text files to show the concept. You can change it for images. Modify readAsText with what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I tried to do. But I could not get the promise working, because I was missing the resolve,reject calls. Thanks. This is a thread-safe approach than the accepted answer (which will work only as long as JS is single-threaded in the browsers).